How to run Safari with JSC_useJIT=false webkit?
I compiled a debug version of webkit and want to use it with Safari.
I'm using run-safari --debug which $DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH is set to WebKitBuild/Debug.
But I want to use safari with webkit that has JIT disabled.
I have export JSC_useJIT=false in .zprofile and using octane, but there is no difference in score, so I'm assuming webkit is still using FTLJIT.
Does anyone know how to use Safari with disabled JIT?
Thanks
